# Why does HashMap.put both compare hashes and test equality?

Tags: java, hashmap

I analyse the `HashMap` source code in Java and get a question about the `put` method.

Below is the `put` method in JDK1.6:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

I get confused about the `if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))`

Why is the condition like this?

Because in Java super class `Object`, there is a [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) of `hashCode` and `equals`:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

So the `key.equals(k)` implies `key.hashCode() == k.hashCode()`.

The `hash()` is below:

```
 static int hash(int h) {
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

thus `key.hashCode() == k.hashCode()` implies `e.hash == hash`.

So why isn't the condition like `if ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))`?

Answer (score 9):

It's just an optimization: comparing two integers is faster than calling `equals()`.

If the two hashcodes differ, then, based on the contract of `equals` and `hashCode`, the map knows that the existing key isn't equal to the given key, and can go faster to the next one.

Answer (score 8):

It's just avoiding a method call when it can: If the hash (which isn't `hashCode()`, it's the map's own hashing) is different from the entry's hash, it *knows* it doesn't have to call `equals` at all. Just optimizing a bit.

Answer (score 1):

value of 'hash' variable can be different to the keys hashcode. 'hash' variable is the result of calling 'hash(key.hashCode())' method. Therefore it's required to compare the hash values and also equality of keys.